# How to unittest a method that print to file?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a method to print some values to a file.

```
from typing import TextIO

def print_to_file(file: TextIO, value: str) -> None:
  print(value, file=file)
```

Here is my current unittest but it will got PermissionError when running unittest on online server. What is the correct way to test it?

```
def test_print_to_file(self):
  file_name = 'temp_file.txt'
  value = '123'
  expected_content = '123\n'

  with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
    print_to_file(file, value)

  with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    self.assertEqual(file.read(), expected_content)
```

Comment: At what step of the test do you get the permission error? Maybe you'd need to create the file in a specific directory where your test process has write permissions, e.g. somewhere in `/tmp`.

Comment: @das-g I will get PermissionError on `with open(file_name, 'w') as file:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed via using [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).

```
import tempfile

def test_print_to_file(self):
  value = '123'
  expected_content = '123\n'

  with tempfile.TemporaryFile('w+t') as file:
    print_to_file(file, value)
    file.seek(0)
    self.assertEqual(file.read(), expected_content )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `+` in w & r   & try

```
      def test_print_to_file(self):
         file_name = 'temp_file.txt'
         value = '123'
         expected_content = '123\n'

         with open(file_name, 'w+') as file:
         print_to_file(file, value)

         with open(file_name, 'r+') as file:
         self.assertEqual(file.read(), expected_content)
```